# Anti-Exploit Server Sided Problem (Character is nil)

Tags: lua, roblox

So I've been trying to create an anti-exploit system, but one that can't be disabled via exploits. and when I try to see if any of the Humanoid's attributes changing, by using (function param1).Character.Humanoid I get an error in the developer console (in game, not below the command line) showing `attempt to index nil with humanoid`

**Code**

```lua
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(p)
while true do
    if p.Character.Humanoid.Health > 100 or p.Character.Humanoid.MaxHealth > 100 then
        p:Kick("Potential Exploiting Detected. [Exploit Protection: Changing Health]")
    end

        if p.Character.Humanoid.WalkSpeed > 16 then
        p:Kick("Potential Exploiting Detected. [Exploit Protection: Increasing Speed]")
    end

    if p.Character.Humanoid.JumpPower > 50 then
        p:Kick("Potential Exploiting Detected. [Exploit Protection: Increasing Jump-Power]")
    end

    if p.Team ~= game:GetService("Teams")["Miners"] then
        p:Kick("Potential Exploiting Detected. [Exploit Protection: Putting Self on a Team]")
    end
    wait(1);
end
end)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you expect `p.Character` to be anything but `nil`?

From the [Roblox manual](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/Character):

> **Character**
>
> ... Initially, this property is nil then set when the player’s
> character first spawns. Use the Player.CharacterAdded event to detect
> when a player’s character properly loads

When a player is added it does not have a Character yet. Also running that in an infinite loop that never breaks, even after the player has been kicked doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know I also needed a Character Added

Comment: Well now I have a problem that it won't detect it if it's a script, the loop won't work with a server sided script

Comment: if oyu have a new problem post a new question with updated code. also consider accepting my answer if your quesiton has been answered. please take the [tour]

Answer (score 0):

PlayerAdded is called, when a player joins the game. When they join the game, the character isn't loaded yet, so it is set to nil. In order to run your code, after the Character is loaded use

```
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(p)
  p.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(c)
    -- TODO
  end)
end)
```